# Sharing with Windows File Services in 2008R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share, file-sharing

I have installed 2008R2, and added the file Server Role.

- Created a volume, and created a new share in that voluem (all from the File Server GUI)

[image]

When my users log to the \servername\ they do not see the share.

[image]

- When I check the folder properties (right click) it says that the folder is not share)

  [image]

My question:

- What does File server manage if it can't set correctly the share options on the shared folder?
- or is my process wrong?

Do I need to still "Enable Sharing" on the folder?  I so hope not too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are sharing through NFS. You should share through CIFS/SMB

Answer (score 0):

You are sharing with NFS (Network File System) which is typically used to share files in a Unix/Linux environment. The Windows world typically uses SMB/CIFS (Server Message Block/Common Internet File System). You can share a folder with SMB/CIFS from the Sharing tab shown in your screenshot, or you can select SMB from the *Provision a Shared Folder Wizard* in the *Share and Storage Management* tool.

[image: Provision a Shared Folder Wizard]